# "search for" in top left of intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Really quick question. I sometimes hit some random hotkey in IntelliJ and it screws up my typing and starts typing in some "search for: " box in the top left near where the top-left of the project view usually is. What hotkey does this? No matter how much I backspace, the box will disappear but once I start typing again I will only type in this weird box.

[image: Here's a link to a gif of it happening.]

The only way I've ever fixed this is by closing and restarting IntelliJ. As you can see, even if I press escape and close it, it still pops up when I start typing again.

Answer (score 0):

This is an incremental search. The key mapping for this will vary according to each user's preferences.

Here's a screenshot, showing that my kep mapping is `CTRL j`

[image]

You'll find your key mapping under `Preferences > Keymap > Other > Incremental Search`.

You can remove / stop the incremental search by hitting `ESC`.